# How to determine if code running in visual studio hosting process

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to determine if code is running in a Visual Studio hosting process?  I have a service that is running and I'll either run it through VS with all the "step through" functionality or run it normally (i.e., start the Windows service).

Comment: close vs? but if i remember right, there is host process window in vs, or you simply use the taskmanager.

Comment: Do keep your eyes on the ball, surely you are *really* interested in Debugger.IsAttached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that seems to work

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        // If running as part of the Visual Studio hosting process then use
        // reflection to invoke the service via reflection (otherwise it does
        // not allow direct starting of a service).  If not in interactive mode
        // then just start and run the service
        if (System.Environment.UserInteractive)
        {
            var service = new HostService();
            MethodInfo onStartMethod = typeof(ServiceBase).GetMethod("OnStart", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            onStartMethod.Invoke(service, new object[] { new string[] { } });

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
        }
        else
        {
            ServiceBase[] services = new ServiceBase[] 
                { 
                    new HostService()
                };
            ServiceBase.Run(services);
        }
    }
```